# information about UML?

Tags: uml

where can i find information about UML?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uml+book

Answer (score 2):

Martin Fowler's [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) is a very good introduction.  It's pragmatic, well-written, and very concise.

Answer (score 1):

Umm... try [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=UML) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) or innumerable books.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UML Resource Page](http://www.uml.org/) of the OMG. Among other resources, this page has links to the latest [UML specifications](http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/modeling_spec_catalog.htm#UML).

There are plenty of good books available as well:

- [The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245628) - Rumbaugh, Jacobson, and Booch
- [The Unified Modeling Language User Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321267974) - Booch, Rumbaugh, and Jacobson
- [UML Distilled](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687) - Martin Fowler